# What is the function in Snowflake to change a decimal (base 10) number to a different base (not binary, octa or hexa)?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to convert a number from decimal (base 10) to base 18 in Snowflake.

I am able to convert this number in **Oracle SQL** with the `to_base` function:

- Decimal number: 8581597126547800
- Function used: `to_base(8581597126547800,18)`
- Output of base 18 number is 7798G1GG5HGE4

I am able to convert this number in **Excel** with the `base()` function:

- Decimal number: 8581597126547800
- Function used: `=base(8581597126547800,18)`
- Output of base 18 number is 7798G1GG5HGE4

What is the function in **Snowflake** that can provide the same result?

Comment: I tried to make your question more readable. What is SF? Can you add an appropriate tag?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I have updated SF to Snowflake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own function like :

```
create or replace function to_base(num double, base double)
returns varchar
language javascript
as
 $$
    return NUM.toString(BASE)
 $$;
```

And then use it directly:

```
 select to_base(8581597126547800, 18);
```

Output:

```
7798G1GG5HGE4
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. I have a followup - this script does not work in Dbeaver. Is there a similar way to code this in Dbeaver?

Comment: Great!  
Feel free to accept it this answers your question :-)  
  
Regarding DBeaver: it works for me. Could you share your error?

Comment: When I run the first part to create a function in DBeaver, I am getting this error:

**SQL Error [90105] [22000]: Cannot perform CREATE FUNCTION. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name.**

Comment: The function needs to be created inside a schema which is itself inside a database. There are two ways to fix this: 1) in your session set the database as well as schema that you want to use. eg. **"use schema mydb.myschema;"** 2) use fully qualified name while creating the function eg. "create or replace function **mydb.myschema**.to_base(num double, base double)...."